# Iphone and Android use Bluetooth HID Protocol?

Tags: android, iphone, serial-port, mouse, hid

I want to make the mobile device discoverable via bluetooth on the computer, and use the Human Interface Device protocol, the same way that an actual bluetooth mouse functions.

From my research I know that this is possible at least on iOS.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647

My question is, how does one connect the mobile device to the computer, and make it use the HID profile specifically, all without the need of a desktop client?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at the opensource [AndroHid](http://code.google.com/p/androhid/) project; which does the same thing for keyboard.